# TYPO3 Upgrade Wizard Fails on DatabaseRowsUpdateWizard

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

i updated a project from TYPO3 7.6 to ^8 by following the official guide. latest steps were the composer update. i removed extensions/packages not compatible with ^8 and updated the ones available for ^8. im able to reach the install tool, the TYPO3 admin backend and the frontend (with errors).
so i ended up at the step were i should use the upgrade wizards provided by the install tool. i completed a few wizards without any issues but then faces a pretty one - first i tried to run DatabaseRowsUpdateWizard within the install tool but that failed with a memory error - i tried the cli approach with

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 vendor/bin/typo3cms upgrade:wizard DatabaseRowsUpdateWizard
```

the processing worked but it ended up with following error:

```
[ Helhum\Typo3Console\Mvc\Cli\FailedSubProcessCommandException ]


#1485130941: Executing command "upgrade:subprocess" failed (exit code: "1")
 thrown in file vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Install/Upgrade/UpgradeHandling.php
 in line 284
```

the command initially failed is:

```
'/usr/bin/php7.2' 'vendor/bin/typo3cms' 'upgrade:subprocess' '--command' 'executeWizard' '--arguments' 'a:3:{i:0;s:24:"DatabaseRowsUpdateWizard";i:1;a:0:{}i:2;b:0;}'
```

and here is the subprocess exception:

```
[ Sub-process exception: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\InvalidPathException ]


#1320286857: File ../disclaimer_de.html is not valid (".." and "//" is not allowed in path).
 thrown in file typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/Driver/AbstractHierarchicalFilesystemDriver.php
 in line 71
```

im pretty much lost and dont know were to start to get this fixed - help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried fixing the broken URLs (which could not work with v7 either) by dropping the `../` part? You'll need to do this manually in your DB before running the migrations.

Comment: did not read about that - do you know what tables?

Comment: @MathiasBrodala additional info: 7.6 worked just fine - i was never running a wizard but in generall everything worked

Comment: You need to check any table with RTE fields, I'd start with `tt_content.bodytext`.

Comment: oh yeah... over 100k entries affected, time to write a little helper.... thanks for help @MathiasBrodala

Comment: OK, I've added a proper answer you can vote on. If your helper is more elaborate than my example, you are free to add it to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues like these usually stem from broken URLs in RTE fields as can be seen in the error output:

> File ../disclaimer_de.html is not valid (".." and "//" is not allowed in path)

In this case you should manually prepare the database and run SQL statements which replace the broken/obsolete `../` prefix from all affected records. An example query:

```sql
UPDATE tt_content
SET bodytext = REPLACE(bodytext, 'href="../', 'href="')
WHERE bodytext LIKE '%href="../';
```

Notice that this query is **very** basic and can destroy your data, so make sure you run some `SELECT` statements first to make sure nothing breaks. Also keep a backup of your database at hand.

Sometime, custom or TER extension also have RTE such as `tt_news` where you might come across same issue. To fix that, you just need to run the same query with the according table.